# Dynamic Angular Components without defining them in entryComponents array

Tags: javascript, angular, plugins

How can we create components dynamically without defining in entryComponents and declarations array.
I would like to include components like plugins(like wordpress plugins) so that angular can scan one folder and run components dynamically, 
I don know if it is possible with angular core, or with any npm module or custom implementation.

However I read the book [Mastering Angular2 Componets Chapter 10](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Mastering-Angular-2-Components/tree/master/angular-2-components-chapter-10)  based on
 [Mastering Angular Components](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/Web%20Development/9781785884641) ,
I tried creating sample angular 4 app with this approach but dynamic components are not getting created without defining them in my module's entryComponents array.
Please suggest any way to achieve this without defining them to entryComponents and declarations,

Comment: you can't use components that are not declared in declarations - read [this article](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e) to understand why. but you can use components not defined in bootstrap if you compile them manually, again this is described in the article in the link

Comment: @nikhil, have you found any solution? I also need to implement this scenario!